# SVG exceeds flex item container

Tags: css, svg, tailwind-css

Example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/21iQsBe9p1?size=758x720

As you scale the viewport, you can see the SVG exceeds the bounds of the `flex-1` container, and pushes the footer off-screen. I can't for the life of me figure out a solution for this.

Note: I'm using Tailwind CSS, however this isn't an issue with Tailwind.

Comment: Note: Don't use [tag:tailwind-css], if your issue is not about Tailwind. You might want to include some code and/or images in your question to make it clear(er) and increase the chances of getting help.

Comment: You are forcing it with this roule: `.h-screen { height: 100vh;}`

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never use Tailwind Css, but you can set `positon: absolute` and left, right, top, bottom set equals to 0 for `svg` element if its container has `position:relative`.

```
<!-- Dynamic height from flex-1 -->
<div class="flex-1 relative">
  <!-- SVG height not fitting to flexible item height -->
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="max-h-full" style="position:absolute;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;right:0;">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"
      class="stroke-current text-blue-500" />
  </svg>
```

In Tailwind CSS you can use classes `absolute` and `inset-0`

```
<!-- Dynamic height from flex-1 -->
<div class="flex-1 relative">
  <!-- SVG height not fitting to flexible item height -->
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="max-h-full absolute inset-0" >
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5"
      class="stroke-current text-blue-500" />
  </svg>
```

[example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/m7QrxZGNj5?size=758x720)

Comment: Perfect! The SVG `max-h-full` is needed to make that work correctly, thanks!!